# How to do predict when trained with Normalization or dropout layer in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, caffe, conv-neural-network

I trained a model with Normalization layer. The code is as this:

**In training phase：**

```
model=Sequential()
model.add()

...

k.set_learning_phase(1)
ModelCheckpoint(weights_file)
model.fit()
```

**In inference time:**

```
k.set_learning_phase(0)
model.load_weights(weights_file)
model.predict_classes()

...
```

The version of Keras：2.0.8. Is that right，or need some special codes to compute the BN after training like using SegNet in Caffe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to do anything special when using BatchNormalization or Dropout layers. Keras already tracks the learning/testing phases, so when using `predict` or `predict_classes`, it does the right thing.

You do not even need to set the learning phase manually, Keras already does it.

Comment: Thanks for your timely reply. I got it.